# Click on LI, show/hide UL

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, menu, navigation

I am trying to do a toggle nav, but I can't seem to figure out whats wrong with my code. It's pretty messy as I am using CMS which has created the id and class used in the list menu. Ideally I would have a better name for the list.

I have posted the code on https://jsfiddle.net/chachacallis/amfmsors/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul ul').hide();
    $('ul li span.section_title a').removeAttr("href");
    $('ul li span.section_title > a').click(function (event) {
        $('ul ul').hide('slow');
        $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle('slow');
    });
});
```

updated
What if i didn't want the default action to be disable for home and other items that do not have a sub menu? how would a add that to the existing code?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your jsFiddle did not include jQuery so it did nothing at all. Secondly, removing the `href` attribute from `a` elements renders them un-clickable. If you want to stop the link action being followed on click you need to use `preventDefault()` on the raised event. Finally, your DOM traversal is incorrect. You need to use `closest('li').find()`, as the `parent()` of the `a` is a `span` which does not contain the `ul`. Putting all that in action, you get something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul ul').hide();
    $('ul li span.section_title > a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('ul ul').hide('slow');
        $(this).closest('li').find('ul').toggle('slow');
    });
});
```

[**Working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/amfmsors/3/)

Comment: Thank you Rory well explained solution!, would mark your answer up but u do not have 15 rep as yet!

Comment: @Tushar it opens fine for me. What's the issue you have?

Comment: It should close if it is open and should open if it is close

Comment: That's down to the OP to decide. I have simply replicated his logic, fixing the implementation errors.

Comment: updated What if i didn't want the default action to be disable for home and other items that do not have a sub menu? how would a add that to the existing code?

Answer (score 0):

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/amfmsors/9/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.section').on('click', 'li a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('li').find('ul').slideToggle();
    $(this).closest('ul').siblings('.section').find('ul').slideUp();
  });
});;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="section_1" class="section active_section">
  <li><span class="section_title active_section_title" id="section_title_1"><a id="section_link_1" href="#">Home</a></span>

    <ul style="display: none;">
      <li>
        a
      </li>
      <li>b
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul id="section_4" class="section">
  <li><span class="section_title" id="section_title_4"><a id="section_link_4" href="#">About</a></span>

    <ul style="display: none;">
      <li>
        a
      </li>
      <li>b
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul id="section_2" class="section">
  <li><span class="section_title" id="section_title_2"><a id="section_link_2" href="#">Lines</a></span>

    <ul style="display: none;">
      <li class="exhibit_title" id="exhibit_12"><a href="#">wellWE</a>

      </li>
      <li class="exhibit_title" id="exhibit_11"><a href="http://localhost/apparel/index.php/license/-marvel/">Arrival</a>

      </li>
      <li class="exhibit_title" id="exhibit_10"><a href="#">Star Home</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul id="section_3" class="section">
  <li><span class="section_title" id="section_title_3"><a id="section_link_3" href="#">Private homeland</a></span>

    <ul style="display: none;">
      <li class="exhibit_title" id="exhibit_13"><a href="#">ttW 15-16</a>

      </li>
      <li class="exhibit_title" id="exhibit_14"><a href="#">ghy15</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul id="section_5" class="section">
  <li><span class="section_title" id="section_title_5"><a id="section_link_5" href="#">contact</a></span>

    <ul style="display: none;"></ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

`$(this).closest('li').find('ul').slideToggle()`: This toggles(hide if shown and vice versa) the `ul` that is in the current menu i.e. submenu ul

`$(this).closest('ul').siblings('.section').find('ul').slideUp()`: This hides all the other open submenus.

Comment: cheers tushar, i had actually updated it to using slide toggle. thanks for you answer